# Configuration Error

Tags: asp.net

what is meaning the error . I set  and  then appear this error .

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

What do I do whit error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a virtual directory for your ASP.NET application as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201127004607/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most obvious solution is to follow the error message: it says that it can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. So go to the IIS management console and configure the virtual directory to be an application. Alternatively, change the configuration to not include the section mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a virtual directory for your application in IIS. To do that in IIS 6, right-click on Default Web Site and choose New, then Virtual Directory. This opens a wizard. You are prompted for an alias, which would generally be the name of the website. On the next screen, browse to the root directory of your web app. For Access Permissions, be sure that Read and Run Scripts are checked. For Execute Permissions, select Scripts Only.

There's a lot more to configuring an app in IIS, but this should get you past the initial step.

To examine other configuration options, right-click on the new website in IIS and choose Properties. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286507.aspx) the MSDN page to get you started.